# My object cannot move, but moving tool shows another position

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

[image]

I face some issues: my object cannot move from the location. Please help to solve this issue so I can continue my work.

Comment: We need more information. Please share your file on  https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: This looks like a GPU problem, make sure your hardware is supported and the drivers up to date

Comment: how i can identified my hardware supported or not

Comment: how i can identified my hardware supported or not